# How to duplicate google sheet as values and formatting only & rename it to a certain cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've entered the code below on Apps Script:

```
function so5691088602(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetname = "Sheet1";
var basesheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
var newSheetName = new Date(basesheet.getRange("B3").getValue());
var NumDups = 30;
for (var i=0;i<NumDups;i++){
basesheet.activate;
var tempDate = new Date();
var printdate01 = Utilities.formatDate(new 
Date(tempDate.setDate(newSheetName.getDate()+1+i)), "GMT+10", "MMMM dd, 
yyyy");
// Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet Date = "+printdate01);
ss.insertSheet(printdate01, {template: basesheet});
}
}
```

It works perfectly by duplicating the active sheet but how do I modify it so it can print the value and formats of the
sheet only and not the formulas as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dataRange.setValues(dataRange.getValues())`, like this:

```
function so5691088602() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dateStart = templateSheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  const numDups = 30;
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  for (let i = 1; i <= numDups; i++) {
    const tempDate = dateOffset_(dateStart, i);
    const sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(tempDate, timezone, 'MMMM dd, yyyy');
    const newSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, { template: templateSheet });
    const dataRange = newSheet.getDataRange();
    dataRange.setValues(dataRange.getValues());
  }
}


/**
* Gets a new Date object that is offset by numDays from date.
*
* @param {Date} date The date from which to count.
* @param {Number} numDays The number of days to add or subtract from date.
* @return {Date} A new Date object that is offset by numDays from date.
*/
function dateOffset_(date, numDays) {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + numDays);
  return newDate;
}
```

Comment: I modified it a-bit but this is all I needed and it works now as intended thanks @doubleunary